# Проблема с JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Почему-то даты перескакивают на понедельник,а не остаются на своих местах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установлены следующие настройки:

```
showOn:"focus",
showAnim:"fadeIn",
showOptions:{},
defaultDate:null,
appendText:"",
buttonText:"...",
buttonImage:"",
buttonImageOnly:!1,
hideIfNoPrevNext:!1,
navigationAsDateFormat:!1,
gotoCurrent:false,
changeMonth:!1,
changeYear:!1,
yearRange:"c-10:c+10",
showOtherMonths:!1,
selectOtherMonths:!1,
showWeek:!1,
calculateWeek:this.iso8601Week,
shortYearCutoff:"+10",
minDate:+1,
maxDate:null,
duration:"fast",
beforeShowDay:null,
beforeShow:null,
onSelect:null,
onChangeMonthYear:null,
onClose:null,
numberOfMonths:1,
showCurrentAtPos:0,
stepMonths:1,
stepBigMonths:12,
altField:"",
altFormat:"",
constrainInput:!0,
showButtonPanel:!1,
autoSize:!1,
disabled:!1
```

Comment: Как понять не остаются на месте и что означают перескакивают на понедельник?

Comment: 16 января это среда, а в календаре отображается как понедельник

Comment: Выложи код весь, будет понятнее

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости у вас в коде есть что-то такого типа

```
.ui-datepicker-unselectable { display: none; }
```

или

```
$('.ui-datepicker-unselectable').hide();
```

из-за этого даты смещаются влево.  Если вы уберете такой код, то даты не будут перескакивать.

Comment: Ни того,ни другого не нахожу

Comment: Тогда куда делись числа от 1 до 15?

Comment: Установлено minDate:+1, числа в календаре выводятся начиная со следующего дня

Comment: @ДимаДомрачев этот плагин не скрывает даты, а делает их недоступными для выбора. Без вашего кода я ванговать больше не буду.